# Old Python 2.7 is still used for my Django application instead of a virtual environment

Tags: python, django

So, I have two different versions of Python on my CentOS machine - 2.7 and 3.4. What I want is to simply run my Django application using Python 3.4 and not that old outdated garbage. To do this I created a virual environment, so that my folder structure now looks like this

```
\vwrapper
    \bin
    \include
    \lib
    \lib64
    ...
```

I created this virtual environment using Python 3.4. After that I activated this environment like so:

```
 $ source vwrapper/bin/activate
 (vwrapper) [root@...]
```

So, I clearly see, that I now inside this virtual environment. I now even can check, that indeed I'm using python 3.4:

```
(vwrapper) [root@...] # python --version 
Python 3.4.5
```

At this stage everything looks good. Then I installed django:

```
(vwrapper) [root@...] # pip install django
```

Again it's ok. In \vwrapper\bin I can now see some django tools. I then use one of these tools to create my first django application:

```
(vwrapper) [root@...] # bin/django-admin startproject accent
```

Looks good. I go to wsgi.py and make a little correction:

```
import os, sys
path = '/var/www/vwrapper/accent'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
```

Then I go to settings.py and also make a little correction:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Great! The only thing that remains to be done is apache virtual host. So, I create this virtual host and restart apache:

```
(vwrapper) [root@...] # apachectl restart
```

Fantastic! When I go to to this host in my browser, I see my first Django application. So far, so good. But the thing is, I see that old Python 2.7 is used, I checked it by returning to browser sys.version:

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse(sys.version)
```

So that, when I restart apache again and go to this page, I see in browser this message:

```
2.7.5 (default, Nov 6 2016, 00:28:07) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)]
```

What the heck? I tried to fix it by putting

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
```

to every .py script, but it does not help. I hope someone knows what may be wrong with that. I spent two days to make it all work, but still I'm in trouble. I do not know what I'm missing. Thanks!

PS. This how my virtual host configuration looks like in Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName django.localhost
    WSGIScriptAlias / "/var/www/vwrapper/accent/accent/wsgi.py"
    <Directory "/var/www/vwrapper/accent/accent">
        Options +ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So, as you can see, I don not mention Python in this config, but probably I should (though, I do not know exactly how).

**EDIT**

I made some corrections to my virtual host configuration, so that it know looks like:

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/vwrapper/accent:/var/www/vwrapper/lib/python3.4/site-packages
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName django.localhost
    WSGIScriptAlias / "/var/www/vwrapper/accent/accent/wsgi.py"
    <Directory "/var/www/vwrapper/accent/accent">
        Options +ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and I also edited my wsgi.py script:

```
import site
site.addsitedir('/var/www/vwrapper/lib/python3.4/site-packages')
```

Restarted Apache, but to no avail. It seems like I did a dozen of steps to use Python 3.4, but still miss one some secret step.

Comment: @e4c5. The question you are pointing to has no answer, just a bunch of references to some outer resources. I really wonder, why you marked my question as a possible duplicate. But if you still beleive, that they are duplicates, would you be so kind to advise what to do to fix my problem?

Comment: Taking into account what I've done by now, can you, please, advise what I'm still missing?

Comment: @e4c5: the problem isn't that the wrong PYTHONPATH is set, the problem is that the wrong interpreter is used.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich. Absolutely correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WSGIScriptAlias / "/var/www/vwrapper/accent/accent/wsgi.py"
```

You are using mod_wsgi to run your Python. Do you use a mod_wsgi that is compiled to use Python 3?

For instance, on Ubuntu, there exist packages `libapache2-mod-wsgi` which uses Python 2, and `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` which uses Python 3. But I don't know about CentOS.

If you can compile mod-wsgi yourself, see https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/installation-issues.html#multiple-python-versions .

Comment: totally agree! probably he forgot to install it.

Comment: You are right! The whole trouble was in mod_wsgi. Thanks!

Comment: Please also read http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html to learn how to setup Python virtual environments correctly. It clearly explains the issue about mixing Python versions. It also describes how the recommended practice is to use mod_wsgi daemon mode and not embedded mode as is being used in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure your Apache is accessing the correct virtualenv. Activate is only working for current shell. Most likely your Apache is having a config file somehow mapping your request to your application.

Comment: What I have in Apache is just a virtual host configuration. Python is not event mentioned in this config file. I will submit the current configuration in a second.

Comment: Please, have a look at my virtual host configuration. It would be great, if you could share, how to specify what virtualenv should be used by Apache. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the same setup with two Python versions I am using following wsgi.py which is working correctly. Did you activate virtualenv inside of wsgy.py? I think the problem goes from this file. Compare it with yours.

```
import os, site, sys

# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('~/virtualenvs/projectenv/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages')

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('/home/ubuntu/project')
sys.path.append('/home/ubuntu/project/project')

# Assign settings module for starting
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'

# Activate your virtual env
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/projectenv/bin/activate_this.py")
exec(open(activate_env).read())

# Load environ variables
from prepare_server import prepare_server
prepare_server()

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: But this doesn't work if wsgi.py is run with Python 2, does it?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I think it should be modified if you want to use it for Python2 because exec works only for Python 3. As I see, author also wants to run Python3